# trying to swape the view like cell swap

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to swap  the view like the cell swap in table view .I google but didn't get any idea .this is new think which i am  trying for me so need help.
If any one have idea hint please give me .
I didn't more information  about this .

Thanks in advance

Comment: i didn't get what you are trying to do or implement please provide some more details on it

Comment: @AalokParikh I have multiple view on the superview i want to swap the view in same way like the Cell swapping

Comment: My View look like the bookshelf in that i want the swap on that view

Comment: ok i got it will try to give you some sort of code if it's working

Answer (score 0):

If your views are all in the same row, you may want to add them to a scoll view and set the paging property to YES.

Anyway, the appropriate solution would be to add a swipe gesture recognizer to the view and use it to receive the swipe event. In the method that you handle the event, move the views using a One of the new UIView animations methods.

You may also consider adding your views to a tableview, and because each cell has a contentView property, you can use it to represent you own view.

Good Luck!